# stop abusive words using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to filter some word(sex etc) using regex, but some time people use that words like that (b a d)(b.a.d)(b/a/d) and so on how to stop these kind of words using regex.

That is only one word I need to filter all that kind of words I have write that code but its not work perfectly

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var a=['bad','worse'];
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){

          var re = new RegExp(a[i],"g");
          var str = "bad words here"; 
          var res = str.match(re);

          if(res.length>0){
                alert(res);
                break;
          }
     }
   });  
 </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hah, good luck. If people want sex, they will find a way. e.g. S三X.  Or, what to do with Sussex? Sextuple? Sextant? Misexample? Imagine censoring "ass": you also censor "pass", "sass", "grass", "ass" (as donkey)...

Comment: Also, regex can filter out text, but not necessarily understand the context the string is in.  For example, "a person's sex is female" is perfectly fine.

Comment: human moderation is the only sure thing

Comment: replace your code to `var res = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').match(re);`

Comment: To account for context, you may wish to replace the blacklisted word with something like "-----" instead of an empty string.  Then, hover effects could be implemented so if someone wished to see a falsely flagged word he or she could

Comment: Buy some Indian service and order them to filter all texts. It will be extra cheap (just like 100% Captcha auto-solver)

Comment: please sir read the code and tell me its not alerting the result

Comment: Better solution to use machine learning, write code to understand meaning of sentence and then avoid it. unfortunately there are thousands of way to bypass this.

Comment: This kind of filtering needs to be done manually, if done at all. There are plenty of examples where a rude word is part of another. If you're going to attempt to incorporate it in your website, you should make the filter optional.

Comment: Take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter

Comment: I think the only viable options today are to find a third-party service with an API or active moderation by humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:** Just use following code:

```js
function isAbusive(str) {
  var badWords = ['bad', 'worst'];
  var isTrue = false;
  if(str) {
     for (var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++) {
       isTrue = !!(str.replace(/\W|\s/g, '').toLowerCase().indexOf(badWords[i]) + 1);
       if(isTrue) break;
     }
  }
  return isTrue;
}


var comments = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(i, comments[i].innerHTML)
  if (isAbusive(comments[i].innerHTML)) {//you can check this comment
    alert("there is bad word");
    comments[i].parentNode.removeChild(comments[i]);
  }

}
```

```html
<p class="user1">I want to do "b/a/d" activity</p>
<p class="user2">I want to do "worst" activity</p>
<p class="user2">I want to do "good" activity</p>
<p class="user2">bad activity</p>
<p class="user3">W/O/R/s/T activity</p>
```

Comment: thanks sir this is working fine but how to use that for spaces like (bad)(b a d)

Comment: So let's say I try to submit "tab advances the cursor through the page". Oh, wait, I can't because it detects "b ad"... Good job breaking it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
return "";
```

This is the only way that you will ever stop people from using words you don't like: don't allow them to use any words at all.

Even if you detect certain words, you will have many problems with it, many of which were given to you in a comment on your question. Swapping characters like in @$$ is all too common, and the nerdier people will know about the Cyrillic characters that look identical to Latin characters - try detecting `sеx` with your regex!

It is infinitely more efficient to take a more social approach to this problem. If your community is disinclined to post such words, then there's no need to worry about it. If you moderate the rare posts that contain such words, then the perpetrator won't be able to do it again and others may think twice before following in their footsteps. I have never had any word filters on my user-submitted content, and while we do get the occasional potty-mouth, they're always super-fast to deal with instead of the many hours that would go into trying to stop them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I **REALLY** would not advise doing it, because it could create some weird situations like filtering out things that in context would be totally fine like "that dog is of male sex".

Having said that  you could do something like... It should work, it's not perfect but it'd do the job.

```
    var filter = ['sex','s/e/x'];
    // and so on for each bad word.
    $(document).text(function(i,txt
    {
     for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) 
     {
     var pattern = new RegExp(filter[i], 'gi');
     var clean = '*'.repeat(filter[i].length);
     txt = txt.replace(pattern, clean);
     }
return txt;
});
```

Hope that helps !

**edit** took me so long to write that code section I didn't see the other answer there.
Go with that imo it looks much nicer and more versatile.